# Google Sheets: Copying Sheet Loses a Few Named Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, copy, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets, one is for "Analysis", and the 2nd ("Data") is for lists (dropdowns etc). This my "Master Copy" that only I can update.

When I've added new features etc to my Master, I copy both the Analysis and Data sheets to an existing copy, which allows anyone to view and use, create their own copy, etc. Then I delete the original sheets in this public spreadsheet, and rename the updated sheets so they don't have "Copy..." in the sheet name.

It seems that after I have copied the updated sheets to the "public" spreadsheet, a few of the Named Ranges disappear.  This is quite a problem.

As a newbie, I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you copying the sheets? Can you show your code?

Comment: I'm just doing it in the UI, right-click Sheet Name > Copy To > Existing Spreadsheet.
I'm wondering if it happens when I delete the original sheet, so I can rename the copy - if a Named Range references a range in the deleted spreadsheet, would it be deleted?

Comment: Yes, but the new named ranges should come over with the copied spreadsheet.  You can test this by looking at the list of named ranges before you delete the two old tabs/sheets.  You should have two sets of named ranges - the ones for the newly copied sheets should be prefaced by their sheetname, " 'Copy of Analysis'!rangename ".

Comment: When you do this, can you see that some named ranges are missing, ie. they didn't get added to your shared spreadssheet when you did the Copy To > Existing Spreadsheet?

Comment: I tested the "public" spreadsheet after I'd copied replacement sheets to it, and it wasn't working as it should, then discovered that some Named Ranges were missing - just a few.
Maybe I should do some testing and check as I'm going as you suggested. Maybe it was a one-off glitch.